# Can I use my own SSL for sub domains which are not using Cloudflare HTTP proxy?

Tags: cloudflare, cdn

I'm using the cloudflare free plan

I have domain.com which will use cloudflare HTTP proxy but i have a subdomain sub1.domain.com which will not use cloudflare's HTTP proxy, can i still use my own SSL and if i go to https://sub1.domain.com will it still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's perfectly fine. Of course you have to install the certificate in the web server that sub1.domain.com is hosted on.